# Passing data model as parameter through 2 pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have 2 pages in a flutter project. The first one is loginPage, which it's used for get user profile through Amplify DataStore query right after the login successful:

```
  void _login() async{
    final username = _usernameController.text.trim();
    final password = _passwordController.text.trim();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( SnackBar( content: Text('Entrando no sistema...aguarde'), backgroundColor: Colors.green ) );
    print('username: $username');
    print('password: $password');
    
    try{
      _amplify.Auth.signOut();
      var authResponse = await _amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password);

      if (authResponse.isSignedIn){
         List<Paciente> _listPacientes = await _amplify.DataStore.query(Paciente.classType, where: Paciente.EMAIL.eq(_usernameController.text.trim()));
         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(_listPacientes.elementAt(0))));
      }
    }
    on AuthException catch (e){
      print(e);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( SnackBar( content: Text(e.message), backgroundColor: Colors.red ) );
    }
    
    
  }
```

And the HomePage whih I'd to show the results of the query executed in previous page (Login):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:hmv/models/ModelProvider.dart';
    import 'package:hmv/views/profile.dart';
    
    
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
    
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required Paciente paciente})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      
      Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
    
      void initState() async{
        super.initState();
        paciente = widget.paciente;
      } 
    
      int _selectedIndex = 0; 
      List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Nome do paciente: ${paciente.nome_completo}'
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.phone,
          size: 150,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.camera,
          size: 150,
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.chat,
          size: 150,
        ),
      ];
      
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
        return Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex)
            ),
          ),
         
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex, //New
            onTap: _onItemTapped, 
            fixedColor: const Color(0xFF0065B3),
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: "Home",
    
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.medical_services),
                label: "Saúde",
              ),
         

     BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: "Perfil",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

But when I try to use the page's parameters, I got the folowing error:

```
The instance member 'paciente' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
    
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required Paciente paciente})
          : super(key: key);
```

replace it with

```
  class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    
      Paciente paciente;
    
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.paciente})
          : super(key: key);
```

also change your State:

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      
     // Remove these lines
    //  Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
    
    //  void initState() async{
   //     super.initState();
   //     paciente = widget.paciente;
    //  } 
    
      int _selectedIndex = 0; 
      List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Nome do paciente: ${widget.paciente.nome_completo}'
        ),
```

Comment: Same error in Text Widget when I try to use the parameter

Comment: Edited answer a bit @ArthurShida